# Is it possible to create a Window or a Linux usable native library (DLL and SO) on a Mac OSX?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, dll, shared-libraries

I created a software that has native components and therefore requires the creation of operating system specific shared libraries (`.dylib` , `.dll` and `.so` ). I have a Mac OSX and I have already created a version of the software that is compatible with Mac OSX machines. I need to release versions that are compatible with other operating systems. Can I simply go on my mac terminal and write:

```
gcc -o c_prog.dll -shared c_prog.c
```

and

```
gcc -o libc_prog.so -shared c_prog.c
```

Or do I have to create the `.so` and `.dll` files on their respective operating systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you suggest is NOT possible. Your compiler can create code for ONE specific target platform, specified by the "host triplet", for example on my linux machine:

```
> gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Meaning of the host triplet ist `$(machine)-$(vendor)-$(operatingsystem)`.

GCC (and probably some other compilers) can be built as a **cross compiler**. This is a compiler with a different target host-triplet from the machine it is running on. For my system (Debian Linux), there is a ready made package of GCC for compiling windows 64bit binaries: `gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64`. So in theory, you can build everything on your system. But don't forget you need the target platform's header files, the matching `binutils` (for things like packaging a shared library) and a linker and standard C library for the target platform. All together is called a **cross toolchain**.

Now you could look around for a cross toolchain to target Linux and Windows on your Mac. Maybe you will find something working. Or you could take the though path and try to compile your cross tools yourself from gcc, glibc and binutils sources.

In the end, I resorted to using a *real* Windows virtual machine for building my software, that I developed on Linux, for Windows. This was a lot easier :)